# Installed python package empty except inside source directory

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, setuptools, python-module, virtualenvwrapper

I'm having trouble importing modules from a package I wrote and installed locally using setuptools. I seem to end up with an empty package unless I explicitly import modules in my `__init__.py`, and even then, it only imports stuff if I'm `cd`'d into the package's source directory.

Here's my package structure

```
foo_project/
|-- setup.py
|-- foo/
|-- |-- __init__.py
|-- |-- moduleA.py
|-- |-- moduleB.py
|-- |-- ...
```

I'm using `virtualenvwrapper`, and want to install the above package in some environment `ENV`, and intend to be able to import the module in some other directory `foo_examples`.

To begin with, my `__init__.py` is empty. To install, I:

- run `workon ENV` to activate the virtual environment
- `cd` into `foo_project`
- run `python setup.py install`

The package seems to successfully install; I can even inspect the egg in `~/.virtualenvs/ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages`, and it seems to have all the right files.

But, when I try to import the module, it appears empty:

```
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>> foo.moduleA
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'moduleA'
```

If, however, I explicitly import my modules in the `__init__.py`, they become accessible:

In `__init__.py`:

```
from . import moduleA, moduleB, ...
```

Then:

```
from foo import moduleA
```

Doesn't throw an error, but only if I'm still in the packages source directory. If I `cd` one level up, I get the same problem.

```
$ cd ..
$ python
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>> foo.moduleA
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'moduleA'
```

I tried looking for related questions, but no luck. I suspect it's either a small error or I'm going about this the wrong way altogether. I'd be grateful for some help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think I've got an Idea!

Because you've written a module you can import it. That's clear. But python can't interprete the script in a module as an attribute. You are doing that by calling it like this:

```
    foo.moduleA
```

Additionally moduleA **.py** is not a attribute , it's a program.
Your code could work if you write the attribute code in moduleA **.py** !

Like this it's possible to get some code as an attribute code in your project!

I hope I could help you!

h_e_u_r_e_k_a

Edit:

This is the code in moduleA.py (for example, this is the answer code:)

```
     def myfunctioninA():
         print('Spam')
         print('test')
```

If you import it in your other file like this:

```
     foo.myfunctioninA()
```

It will print `Spam` and `test`

The module should have a different name than the package.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is not clear. Could you give some concrete examples as to what you mean by "write the attribute code in moduleA.py"?